# Receive bipolar analog signal with sampling rate of 10 kHz

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, esp32

I  wish to receive time-stamp data of a bipolar analog signal (analog signal that oscillates about 0 volts) from a sensor (which can only send analog data as an output) into ESP32 at Nyquist sampling rate (Fs) of 10kHz.

Also I wish to transit this data further to Raspberry-Pi for its further post-processing.

Is it possible to achieve this task with the help of ESP32 and RaspberryPi?

Is somebody who has worked on ESP32, could please let me know on how do we go about this, I would be very much thankful!

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please narrow the scope to something specific. Also, what does the "time-stamp data" have to do with anything?

Comment: Look into using ready-to-go firmware for ESP modules like Tasmota, it might be able to do what you need to do without requiring any programming. https://tasmota.github.io/docs/

Comment: I would not use an ESP32 because the timing is interrupt based; which means you set the timer to interrupt 10K times per sec (10KHz) and in the ISR function, you read the ADC value. but many other software factors, affect this timings. (e.g. another higher priority interrupt, memory writes because of OS) so the time stamp wouldn't be exact. this is not a very bad thing in many situations but you mentioned *Nyquist sampling rate*. the nyquist rate is important when you are processing in frequency domain, and an interrupt based 10KHz sampled signal won't be exact.

Comment: Hi @ElliotAlderson. I wish to do frequency domain analysis for which I need time vector and the voltage vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mels for your valuable feeback. I shall look into Tasmota.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TirdadSadriNejad for your valuable suggestions. You have mentioned it right that I wish to perform frequency domain analysis for which Fs=10kHz. Could you please let me know, which could be the best alternate option for ESP32 to achieve Fs=10kHz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

despite being an opinion based question, I would not use an ESP32 because the timing is interrupt based; which means you set the timer to interrupt 10K times per sec (10KHz) and in the ISR function, you read the ADC value. but many other software factors, affect this timings. (e.g. another higher priority interrupt, memory writes because of OS) so the time stamp wouldn't be exact. this is not a very bad thing in many situations but you mentioned *Nyquist sampling rate*. the nyquist rate is important when you are processing in frequency domain, and an interrupt based 10KHz sampled signal won't be exact. so what would I use ?

I had a similar project, so I chose a `STM32` mcu. I set the timer to trigger ADC in that frequency (this is a specific feature, to `trigger the ADC with a timer without any software intervention` or intruption) and the DMA which would copy the sampled value in a memory location. all of the above, is done without cpu interaction. at the middle, or end of a DMA transactions (which can be up to 65536 transactions), an interrupt could be generated by DMA unit for CPU to handle recorded data (e.g. dumping them to uart or an eeprom memory). the DMA part is not very critical and could be omitted, but the timer trigger for ADC is.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TirdadSadriNejad for your valuable suggestions. As I am new to this field and with zero knowledge about STM32 and DMA, could you please suggest me of some useful links/documentations etc so that I can make some basic project and gain some basic understanding.

Comment: actually this method needs a little experience using stm32 microcontrollers. youtube is a good source. (e.g. Controllers Tech channel)